# Rails Asset Path Without Application Root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a rails application that shares some assets with other applications on the same server. The root URL of the rails application is `domain.com/rails-app`, but the assets are all hosted at `domain.com/assets/....` For some reason, rails is adding that /rails-app root context to the asset path.

It happens even if I use a different asset host config setting, i.e. `http://google.com/rails-app/....` How can I configure things so that helpers like `image_tag` and `stylesheet_tag` look at paths that start from the site root?

Comment: Can you post your exact setting for the asset host config?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to use image and stylesheet on `domain.com/rails-app` using URL (other host) from `domain.com`.

### Application on `domain.com/rails-app`

Configuring action controller for `assets_host`, setting `config.action_controller.asset_host` in production environment, production.rb

`config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://domain.com"`

### Application on `domain.com`

You just setting `config.assets.prefix`, By default :

> config.assets.prefix defines the prefix where assets are served from.
>   Defaults to /assets.

[source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config.assets.prefix)

1. In `config/application.rb`

   `config.assets.enabled = true`
2. You can add :

   `config.assets.prefix = ''` set it to empty string
3. restart your server

---

Example

link like this on `domain.com/rails-app`

`<%= image_tag 'logo.png' %>`

will now result in the following link

`<img src="http://domain.com/images/logo.png?1193172652" />`

Comment: Sorry, miss understanding. I think you would like to eliminate the `assets` from your url, so you have more than one application in one server? and then, you want to take assets_path from another application?